# SwiftUI perform action when View disappears or is backgrounded

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI `View`, and I would like to perform an action whenever the `View` becomes no longer visible.  The `View` is not a full screen, it is just a sub view that is then used by another, fullscreen `View`, and as a result does not have a corresponding view controller.  When I use the `.onDisappear` method, it works only when the view disappears but the app is still open.  However, if the app is backgrounded while on that `View`, then `.onDisappear` is not called.  I need to perform an action anytime it's no longer visible, which includes when someone clicks to another screen, as well as when the app is backgrounded. What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: I think you're not able to perform actions while your app is backgrounded

Comment: @JonasLang what about when it's about to be backgrounded?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe the `willResignActiveNotification` within an `.onReceive` modifier.

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { (_) in
          print("UIApplication: background")
}
```

See here: [Detecting a SwiftUI App’s Active, Inactive, and Background State](https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-tips-detecting-a-swiftui-apps-active-inactive-and-background-state-a5ff8acf5db1)

Answer (score 0):

The "SwiftUI way" to do this is to look for changes to the `.scenePhase`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { scenePhase in
                switch scenePhase {
                case .background:
                    print("Background")
                case .inactive:
                    print("Inactive")
                case .active:
                    print("Active")
                @unknown default:
                    break
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this have to be in the top level view of the app? I tried it in my subview and it did not work.

Comment: It works on any view. Just to confirm I created an `OtherView` and displayed it inside a `ZStack`, inside a `VStack` and it worked as above.

Comment: Ah ok, then I'm not sure why it's not working. The onChange is not detecting any change and is not printin anything.

Comment: Please add a minimal version of the code that's not working to your question

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, the View structs are just data that describe what should be shown on screen, i.e. the UI is driven by changes in data. So it's best to solve this problem by putting the action where the data is changed that causes the the thing on screen to be removed e.g.

```
struct MyConfig {
   var isPresented: Bool = false {
       didSet {
           // some logic
       }
   } 
 

   mutating func present(data: Something) {
       isPresented = true
       // some logic
   }

   // other places for logic
   // mutating func cancel() {
   // mutating func hide() {

}

@State var config = MyConfig()

Button("Show") {
    config.present(data: something)
}

.sheet(isPresented: $config.isPresented)
```